# Repeating regex in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I need to parse the line similar to the:

```
'''Object{identifier='d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f', name='some_name2', identifier='d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f', name='some_name3', value=value_without_quotes}'''
```

The line is much longer, but the pattern is the same.

Basically, I need a list (or dict) with key, value. Something like:

```
["'identifier', ''d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f''", "'name', ''some_name2''", "'identifier', ''d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f''", "'name', ''some_name3''", "'value', 'value_without_quotes'"]
```

I ended up with the following regular expression:

```
r'Object{(+?)=(+?)}'
```

It works only if I need the only one object. I'm expecting something like

```
((+?)=(+?),)+
```

to be worked, but it's not.
For example,

```
re.match(r'Object{((.+?)=(.+?),?)+}', line3).groups()
```

Gives me:

```
("some_name3', value=value_without_quotes", "some_name3', value", 'value_without_quotes')
```

As you can see 'value=value_without_quotes' appeared. r'Object{(([^=]+?)=(.+?),?)+}' doesn't work also.

So the question is how to repeat the above in sequence? The thing is that I don't if the value contains quotes, symbols or digits.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try using `findall` instead of `match`? You don't need the `'Object{` at the beginning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may face this problem in an easier way.

```
sentence = '''Object{identifier='d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f', name='some_name2', identifier='d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f', name='some_name3', value=value_without_quotes}'''
listing = [couple.split("=") for couple in sentence.split(",")]
```

Flat the list

```
listing = [y for x in listing for y in x]
```

And you will obtain something like:

```
['Object{identifier', "'d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f'", ' name', "'some_name2'", ' identifier', "'d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f'", ' name', "'some_name3'", ' value', 'value_without_quotes}']
```

The you have just to `strip()` and remove "Object{" and "}"

```
result = [x.strip().replace("Object{", "").replace("}","") for x in listing]
```

Final result is:

```
['identifier', "'d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f'", 'name', "'some_name2'", 'identifier', "'d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f'", 'name', "'some_name3'", 'value', 'value_without_quotes']
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an easier solution. It works. I'm considering your idea. But still, I'd like to understand how to do so with regex.

Comment: @DanielSmialkowsky I posted a solution using regex, but I think this one is better for you case (at least is more pythonic). Note that in both solutions you can skip flattening the list and keep some nested structure with the key:value pairs; but you can't use a dictionary since some keys would be repeated (e.g. 'identifier').

Answer (score 1):

```
line3 = '''Object{identifier='d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f', name='some_name2', identifier='d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f', name='some_name3', value=value_without_quotes}'''

pattern = r'[{\s](.+?)=(.+?)[}\s,]'
match = re.findall(pattern, line3)
[item for key_value_pair in match for item in key_value_pair]
```

Outputs

`['identifier', "'d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f'", 'name', "'some_name2'", 'identifier', "'d6e461c5-fd55-42cb-b3e8-40072670fd0f'", 'name', "'some_name3'", 'value', 'value_without_quotes']`